# SQL multiple group by, aggregate by first group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions

I Currently have written an sql query like this:

```
SELECT   a, b, count(id) / ????
FROM     X
group by a, b
```

Please pay attention to the **?????** in the code above.
There are two groups in `group by`. Namely by columns `a` and `b`.

What I intend to do is to divide the **(1)** count of items in the second group (`b`) to the **(2)** count of items in the first group (`a`).

`count(id)` accomplishes (1). But I don't know what to write for (2).

P.S.: However I know It is possible to replace "????" with another complex select query, but I want to learn if there is a simpler way to `aggregate` items of first Group by.

Update:
Sample data:

```
id       a           b
______________________
1       'A'         'G'
2       'A'         'H'
3       'A'         'H'
4       'B'         'G'
5       'B'         'G'
6       'B'         'K'
7       'B'         'K'
```

results:

```
a           b          [unnamed]
________________________________
'A'         'G'        0.33333
'A'         'H'        0.66667
'B'         'G'        0.5
'B'         'K'        0.5
```

The third column is the percentage of columns with values as in column b relative to values in column a.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What is the first group?  What is the second group?

Comment: First, `count(*)` as I have learned is not what you want, it selects all columns and on large tables, this can be a performance hit. You may want to switch to `count(eventid)` assuming that `eventid` does exist and is your primary key.

Comment: Yes @Roland. count(eventid) is correct. however as i tested count(*) is also working identical. I am editing the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Then an idea might be, that you use views (see `CREATE VIEW`) for each count and then select (means "materializing") both views. But this could be a performance hit again as these `SELECT`s and views can be "expensive" on large tables with many millions of rows. Maybe a better solution is to switch to a programmatic/SQL approach. First use your programming language's "count rows" method/function, then divide both and make sure division-by-zero does not happen.

Comment: @AliJey yes, sure it produces the same result as primary key or all columns are both unique and will give you same row count.

Comment: @AliJey and which SQL dialect are you using? @LONG 's proposed SQL doesn't work on MariaDB, complaining that `OVER` is a syntax error. Please also add then a proper tag to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works if you are using SQL Server

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  a, b, (COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY a, b)* 1.0/COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY a)) as unnamed
FROM Sample
```

Comment: I Tried it and it seems to work. Since I edited the question, can you change the column names so it conforms to the question and is more clear?

Comment: Can you try an `EXPLAIN` in front of it and check how it is performing? I hope your DBMS support this.

Comment: @Roland, ur right, I assumed this is in sql server, seems op is not using that

Comment: In my case This answer (query) takes 14 Seconds to execute. While Tree Frog's answer does it almost instantly. However this answer suits the question requirements more.

Answer (score 2):

```
select A.a, B.b, a.num, b.num, CAST(b.num as float) / cast(a.num as float)
from
(select a, count(*) as num
from @table 
group by a) as A
join 
(select a, b, count(*) as num
from @table
group by a, b) as B on A.a = B.a
```

Comment: Please use backticks around your code. Like `SELECT foo FROM bar`.